# bootstrap nav bar nested <ul> not showing properly under parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

When you view the page as mobile the main navigation bar does not show the drop downs properly underneath their respected parent link.  I have search and cannot seem to find a solution.  Currently the dropdown menus show under and to the left of the main link. You can see a live demonstration at http://beta.lofbc.org

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" href="#">Life of Faith Bible Church</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "index", "Home")</li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/about" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true">ABOUT US <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Church Services", "ChurchServices", "About")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("What to Expect", "WhatToExpect", "About")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("What we Believe", "whatwebelieve", "About")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Leadership", "Leadership", "About")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MINISTRIES <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Children", "Children", "Ministries")</li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Faith-Agents-Academy-FAA-1421388411492935/" target="_blank">FAA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/GodsGirlzClub/" target="_blank">God's Girlz Club</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.aftershockyouth.lofbc.org" target="_blank">AfterShock Youth</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Young Adults</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/menofimpactfellowship" target="_blank">Men of Impact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.jeannefraser.org" target="_blank">Women</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">God's Golden Girls</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">The Great Giveaway</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("EVENTS", "", "Events")</li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MEDIA <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Live Stream</a></li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service Archives", "ServiceArchives", "Media")</li>
                        <li><a href="#">TV Broadcast</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photo Album</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://store.lofbc.org" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CONTACT <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Send us a Message", "index", "contactus") </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submit Testimony</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Prayer Request</a></li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Give", "Donate", "Giving")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your nested `<ul>` tags are absolutely positioned. An absolutely positioned element cannot move relatively positioned elements so even if you moved it across it will simply appear on top of your existing buttons.

My fix would be to apply the following css to the nested `<ul>` tags:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1c5168;
    }

    .nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
        color: lightblue;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Placing it inside a media query will stop the css from applying to your menu on desktop layouts.

You will still have to add more styling to get the menu to look nice but this will fix your positioning issue.

Just for reference here is a good article about the position property with examples of how it works: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/